# Forward declaring a nested enum with G++

Tags: gcc, c++11, forward-declaration

The following code fails to compile with g++:

```
class MyClass {
  public:
    enum MyEnum : int;
};

enum MyClass::MyEnum : int {
  Value1;
};

int main()
{
  auto i = MyClass::Value1;
}
```

It generates the error:

```
"MyClass::EnumValue Value1 is private within this context"
```

The code compiles fine with clang and MSVC 2012.

However, if you either fully scope the enumeration value:

```
int main()
{
  auto i = MyClass::EnumValue::Value1;
}
```

*or*

Make `MyClass` a struct:

```
struct MyClass {
  public:
    enum MyEnum : int;
};
```

The code compiles with g++.

It would appear that I'm hitting this compiler bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49604 but it seems difficult to believe that something so basic could have gone unfixed in g++ for > 3 years.

So, am I misunderstanding the spec? Is GCC in error? Are the other compilers in error? I want to make sure my code is as correct and portable as possible.

Comment: So the code is correct and now compiles fine with gcc 7 or later. The bug fixed in gcc 7.